# How to select Multiple options across multiple Slicers in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to select "Desktop" from 1st slicer and and "Last Week" from 2nd slicer, but as it turns out, i can select only one option from one slicer at a time, i want to highlight only last week values for desktop category,

**Note:** i tried Hierarchy Slicer from Market, but if i select Desktop/Last week and Mobile/Last week both at a same time, the visual is not being displayed.

The following are the pictures of what i am trying to do here:

[image: hierarchy slicer]

[image: Demo Data]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A hierarchy doesn't really make sense. Why can't you use two separate slicers?

Comment: Exactly, i am trying to use 2 slicers which should be buttons and i want to choose multiple options, lets say, "desktop & mobile " and "Last Week" which i cant unless i use basic slicers where i can toggle multiple selections in format options.

Comment: You can definitely make multiple selections on a single slicer and multiple selections across multiple slicers. If the custom slicer you're using doesn't work like that, try the ChicletSlicer from the store. It should be similar.

Comment: the ChicletSlicer works like charm!, Thank you @AlexisOlson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with the regular Slicer as far as possible.

You can make multiple selections by holding down the Ctrl key on your keyboard while clicking.  You can also change the Format of the Slicer, under **Select Controls** turn **Single select** off.  This gives a multi-select UI.

Comment: Ya, after all this time.. i ended up using default slicers.. forgot to respond to this thread early. Thanks for the help though.